# JS переключение по кнопкам с одним активным окном

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

При нажатии на конкретный элемент - `infoStuff` (их всего 12 штук) - должно открываться конкретное окно и, если было открыто другое окно, то оно закрывается - то есть может быть открыто только одно окно. Так же, при нажатии на любую другую часть страницы (кроме самого окна) - окно закрывается.

Реализовал это с помощью простого добавление класса `open`, к уже существующему, готовому контенту в HTML

```
const infoStuff = document.getElementsByClassName('infoStuff')

for (let i = 0 ; i < infoStuff.length; i++) {
    infoStuff[i].addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        showInfoStuff (el)
    }, false);
}

function showInfoStuff (el) {

    const find = el.target.closest('.infoStuff')
    const stuffFind = find.nextElementSibling.firstChild.nextSibling

    if (stuffFind.classList.contains('open')) {
        stuffFind.classList.remove('open')
    } else {
        stuffFind.classList.add('open')
    }

    function closeClick(el) {
        if (el.target.closest('.popup') || el.target.closest('.infoStuff')) {
            console.log('open')
        } else {
            stuffFind.classList.remove('open')
            document.removeEventListener('click', closeClick, false)
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', closeClick, false)

}
```

С помощью переменной `stuffFind`, которую я создаю в функции `showInfoStuff()` - определяю как раз таки то окно, которое нужно открыть. В функции `closeClick()` я добавляю возможность закрытия окна, если клик был не по окну.

Проблема в том, что при этом коде, при открытие второго окна - первое не закрывается... Пробовал решить эту проблему множеством разных способом - обычно всё сводилось к тому, что при нажатии на `infoStuff` открывается только одно окно, НО при повторном нажатии на `infoStuff` - оно не закрывается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста - как мне решить данную проблему? Несколько дней на это угробил уже... Всё никак не могу понять...

Сорри, если код не слишком "профессиональный" :)

Comment: перед открытием нового окна тупо закрой все окна

Comment: Проблема в том, что не знаю, как это сделать :) @Jean-Claude
Например, пробовал таким кодом, но что-то не выходит... 

`const openClass = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-bodyStuff.open') 
if (openClass) openClass.forEach( (e) => { 
console.log('e') 
e.classList.remove('open') 
})`
Точнее, `.forEach` даже не срабатывает (ни вывода в консоль, ни удаления класса `open` у элементов)